# SQL Query to get IDs of rows based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

As an example, if I have a table:

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE
( SectionID INT,
  DetailID INT)
```

I have the following data:

```
SectionID    DetailID
1000          -1
1000           0
1000          -1
1100          5000
1100          0
1200          0
1200          0
1300          7000
1300          8000
```

How do I write the SQL to get all Section Ids that have ALL Detail IDs of 0 or -1. In the above example, the SQL should return 1000 and 1200 (not 1100 as atleast 1 item is not a 0 or a -1)

Comment: you want a result set that has section ids who ONLY have a detail id of 0 or -1 and not any other detailid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SectionID
FROM @tmpTable AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM @tmpTable AS tt
        WHERE tt.SectionID = t.SectionID
          AND tt.DetailID NOT IN (-1, 0)
      )
```

I think this should work too, since `DetailID` is an integer and the values you are checking (`-1` and `0`) have no gaps between them. And it could be faster, with an index on `(SectionID, DetailID)`:

```
SELECT SectionID
FROM @tmpTable AS t
GROUP BY SectionID
HAVING MAX(DetailID) <= 0
   AND MIN(DetailID) >= -1
```

Comment: Why the `<= 0`? I think we can simply do a `MAX(DetailID) = 0 AND MIN(DetailID) = -1` right?

Comment: No. Your `1200` example has both MAX and MIN as 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sectionId from mytable where detailId in (0,-1)
and section id not in (select sectionid from mytable where detail_id > 0)
```